# Google Apps Script Copy/Paste Filtered DataSet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, filter, copy-paste

I've been trying to write a script that simply takes a filtered data, copies it, and then pastes it into another sheet. Nothing I seem to do works. With the code below, which I found online, it should work, but I keep getting an error that states The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. However, I have data in the range A7:R500 and I'm only filtering out blanks and 'W'. Am I correct in this thinking?

```
function copyPaste(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange('A7:R500').getValues();

  var hiddenValues = ['', 'W'];
  values = values.filter(function(v){
    return hiddenValues.indexOf(v[4]) == 'W';
  });

  sheet.getRange(1,21, values.length, 18).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: indexOf() returns and integer not the element of the array. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: so you can try v[4]=='W'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

Since you are already using a filter Array, you can compare `hiddenValues.indexOf(v[4])` to -1 to filter out blanks and "W".

Also, since your goal is to paste the results in a different sheet, you need to define both the source and the destination sheet. Create a sheet and plug its name into the `new sheet name` tag in the code below.

**Sample Code:**

```
function copyPaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('<new sheet name>');
  var values = sheet1.getRange('A7:R500').getValues();
  var hiddenValues = ['', 'W'];
  values = values.filter(function(v){
    return hiddenValues.indexOf(v[4]) == -1;
  });
  sheet2.getRange(1,21, values.length, 18).setValues(values);
}
```

**Reference:**

[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting an error: "Cannot read property 'getRange' of null for line sheet1.getRange('A7:R500').getValues();

Comment: I edited my answer as it seems your sheet name is not the default Sheet1. Also, the name of the destination sheet should be entered in the code as well.

Comment: Had to change indexOf(v[4]) = -1

Comment: Had to change the indexOf(v[4]) = -1 to indexOf(v[4]) == -1, but it works!. Thanks!